# сбрасывается иконка кнопки в кастомном ListView

Tags: android

Вывожу из БД слова в ListView путем кастомного адаптера. Слово может быть избранным. В кастомном listview есть кнопка нажав на которую можно сделать слово избранным или убрать из избранного. Вроде бы все работает, но есть проблемка: Вот нажал на кнопку добавить в избранное слово добавилось, иконка изменилась, затем прокрутил список вверх или вниз и опять в проктурил до того пункта списка которое сделал избранным, но у него иконка осталась такой как будто слово не добавилось в избранное, хотя на самом деле добавилось и в БД произошли изменения. Вот код моего адаптера. Подскажите где я что упустил?

```
public class WordsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context ctx;
    LayoutInflater lInflater;
    ArrayList<SingleWord> words;

    WordsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SingleWord> words) {
        ctx = context;
        this.words = words;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return words.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return words.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;

        SingleWord p = getSingleWord(position);

        if (convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.txtAlphabet = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtAlphabet);
            viewHolder.txtWord = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtWord);
            viewHolder.btnFavorites = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnFavorites);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.txtWord.setText(p.word);
        viewHolder.txtAlphabet.setText(p.alphabet);
        viewHolder.btnFavorites.setImageResource(p.bntIcon);
        viewHolder.btnFavorites.setFocusable(false);
        viewHolder.favorites = p.favorites;

        if (viewHolder.favorites.equals("1")) {
            viewHolder.btnFavorites.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_star_yellow);
        } else if (viewHolder.favorites.equals("0")) {
            viewHolder.btnFavorites.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_star_outline_black);
        }

        viewHolder.btnFavorites.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String selectedItem = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                if (selectedItem.equals("что-то")) {
                    if (viewHolder.favorites.equals("1")) {
                        String wordStr = viewHolder.txtWord.getText().toString();
                        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                        values.put(SlovarEntry.COLUMN_FAVORITES, "0");

                        long newRowId = db.database.update(SlovarEntry.TABLE_RUS, values, SlovarEntry.COLUMN_WORD + "= ?", new String[]{wordStr});
                        viewHolder.favorites = "0";
                        if (newRowId == -1) { // Если ID  -1, значит произошла ошибка
                            Toast.makeText(ctx, "Ошибка", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(ctx, "Удалено из избранное", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            viewHolder.btnFavorites.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_star_outline_black);
                        }
                    } else if (viewHolder.favorites.equals("0")){
                        String wordStr = viewHolder.txtWord.getText().toString();
                        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                        values.put(SlovarEntry.COLUMN_FAVORITES, "1");

                        long newRowId = db.database.update(SlovarEntry.TABLE_RUS, values, SlovarEntry.COLUMN_WORD + "= ?", new String[]{wordStr});
                        viewHolder.favorites = "1";
                        if (newRowId == -1) { // Если ID  -1, значит произошла ошибка
                            Toast.makeText(ctx, "Ошибка", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(ctx, "Добавлено в избранное", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            viewHolder.btnFavorites.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_star_yellow);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    SingleWord getSingleWord(int position) {
        return ((SingleWord) getItem(position));
    }
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtAlphabet;
    TextView txtWord;
    ImageButton btnFavorites;
    String favorites;
}
```

Класс для пункта списка

```
public class SingleWord {
    String word;
    String alphabet;
    int bntIcon;
    String favorites;

    SingleWord(String w, String a, String f, int b) {
        word = w;
        alphabet = a;
        bntIcon = b;
        favorites = f;
    }

    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }

    public String getAlphabet() {
        return alphabet;
    }

    public String getFavorites() {
        return favorites;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том что масив words не знает когда вы добавили-убрали из избраного слово. Вам нужно оновлять значение поля favorites для слова и тогда все будет ок. ListView держит в памяти несколько елементов и при прокрутке пересоздает отобраение, нотак как значение в масиве ничего не слышало о изминение у вас так все и получается

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду через сеттер установить значение переменной favorites после того как в БД обновилось значение?

Comment: сделал через сеттер обновление поля favorites, но не помогло. Делаю так p.setFavorites("0"); где p - объект типа SingleWord

Comment: SingleWord p = getSingleWord(position);
это локальная перемана и все что вы с ней делаете ничего не даст.

вам нужно что-то типа:
words.get(position).setFavorites(1 или 0) и разместить внутри обратотчика клика